# Do we need tags like UIButton, UILabel, etc?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at the `iOS` questions, I often run into tags like [uibutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uibutton), [uilabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uilabel), [uialertview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uialertview), etc. Basically for almost every class in the `UIKit` framework there's a corresponding SO tag.

Some of those tags, like [uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiwebview) correspond to complicated classes that might deserve a separate tag, however [uibutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uibutton), [uilabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uilabel) don't need separate tags (IMO).

Are these tags necessary? Do they add value to the site, or add noise to an already large taxonomy?

**Edit:** Here's a very good post about burninating tags in general: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

Comment: I say Burniate them!

Comment: I say keep them!

Comment: UISwitch tags like UIButton, UILabel on/off?

Comment: `however [uibutton], [uilabel] surely don't need tags` Why? I don't understand your motivation here. If OP has a question about UILabel, why not tag as such?

Comment: I tend to agree. We don't have an [tag:html-button] or [tag:html-label] tag.

Comment: Maybe `surely` was a little bit exagerated, I removed that. For example look at the questions on [tag:uibutton], most of them contain `UIButton` in their title; we have redundancy here, and for most of the question we cannot remove the tag from the title like we do with other tags without affecting its readability.

Comment: Having tag for `UIKit` makes sense. Having tags for each individual control is totally meaningless.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: On the contrary, UIKit is too broad to be useful. What useful distinction do you draw between UIKit and Cocoa Touch, for the purposes of categorizing a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I agree.  I mean, do we really want to group [all of the classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/) in UIKit into one tag?  It doesn't make sense.  If we do, we'll start seeing questions tagged with the ambiguous [tag:button] and [tag:label] tags.  Additionally, there are differences in the implementation of UIKit in Cocoa vs Cocoa Touch.  I don't think they should be grouped together.  People will start confusing [tag:uitextfield] with [tag:nstextfield].

Comment: @Cristik UIKit contains more than just [tag:uibutton] and [tag:uilabel].  Are you saying that questions about [tag:uievent] and [tag:uilexicon] fall under the same category as [tag:uibutton] and [tag:uilabel]?  I don't think so.

Comment: @JAL I didn't say something like this. As I mentioned in the question some of the classes from [tag:UIKit] might deserve a separate tag.

Comment: @Cristik So who arbitrarily decide which classes would get their own tag, and which would be grouped under the umbrella UIKit tag?

Comment: @JAL [tag:uievent] is abused, most of the questions have this tag because the code had `UIEvent` somewhere written, [tag:uilexicon] has 8 questions, out of which 3 qualify for this tag.

Comment: @JAL we need to discriminate of which tags worth to be on stackoverflow, and which don't. We can't have tag for every possible class, that's simply not feasible .What would happen  for example if we'd had tags for every possible `HTML` tag (especially as the set of `html` tags is virtually infinite)

Comment: @Cristik The examples are arbitrary.  What about [tag:uilocalnotification], [tag:uiimage], [tag:uipasteboard], [tag:uiviewcontroller].

Comment: @Cristik I understand but even the act of "grouping" certain tags together is opinion based.  What if Apple changes a class?  I don't see the benefit of having some tags grouped into [tag:uikit] while other tags remain.  You also haven't addressed my question with regard to the UIKit differences with Cocoa and Coca Touch.  If we're burninating [tag:UITextView] will [tag:NSTextView] be removed as well?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you believe "When to burninate", to which you've linked, supports your raising of this question? The first two of the four tests opposing burning are unambiguously passed by these tags; the fourth is passed as well, and note that the alternative [button] + [cocoa-touch] uses a tag that _fails_ that fourth test. The third test is the point of issue: do these tags add meaningful information? I believe they do. If you think they do not, please explain why.

Comment: @JAL, Josh Caswell, I didn't propose burnicating them, nor I proposed merging them. I felt like they don't have a purpose and I wanted to see the community take on this.

Comment: @JAL people add the `ios` tag when asking questions that relate to Cocoa Touch, this is enought

Comment: I spend way too much time answering iOS questions. I firmly believe that at least some of the class-specific tags are useful. For example tags for `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are useful. I know table views very well but have hardly any experience with collection views. Those tags help me focus on or ignore such questions. But I agree that tags for simple widgets are largely useless such as the `UIButton` and `UILabel` tags. Some classes clearly need their own tags, some clearly don't. And there's too much grey in between.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Do you think that all newbies know they should use Cocoa Touch and not UIKit? When they look at their code they will see UIKit. But, I am not really defending UIKit tag here. My point is more that really such minor tags should be removed. They don't make things easier to find (or we should start re-tagging all questions containing UIButton), and just add irrelevant noise.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha But there is [tag:htmlbutton] and [tag:htmltext]

Comment: IMHO we should keep those tags, using UIKit for tagging a question about UIButton seems odd to me, by using specific tag can attract attention of users who has good knowledge about that specific control. I usually check questions on some specific UIKit elements (Because I'm much familiar with those controls) and ignore some of those (Because I'm only have a very basic understanding about it). So removing such tags will negatively affect users like me.

Answer (score 4):

Unless these UI object classes behave exactly the same, with no quirks whatsoever, I would say keep them.  Judging by the fact that many people seem to be interested enough in the **specific** behavior of specific control classes, is evidence that the categorization is serving a useful purpose.

Also, by the criteria you linked, these tags meet all 4.

What is the noise?

Removing these tags would make finding relevant answers to specific questions harder.  I don't see the upside of burninating, other than rep candy and busy work, but that seems to be the main impetus behind many burninates in general.

Comment: If that's the criteria, we need a tag for every combination of every method/class and platform.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful tag groupings are my expertise. If exactly the same set of expertise and interest is going to cover both sets of questions, then one tag makes a more useful taxonomy. If there are people out there that are experts in one but clueless about another, then having multiple tags might make sense.

I agree with your analysis that most of those related UI classes should probably just be tagged with a generic tag. Your exception for UIWebView is also reasonable if that widget is sufficiently complex to be an art in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers seem to assume that we somehow have to have a special tag for saying all of *this is a widget of toolkit thebestone on platform thetrueone* at once.

Which is a misuse of tagging.

Just use one tag for the language, one for the platform, one for the toolkit you decided to abuse, and one tag for whatever thing you are woking with.

[swift] [ipad] [uikit] [button] [textview] (Using two in this example)

Or if I don't care what toolkit is used:

[swift] [ipad] [button] [textview]

Comment: Something has just occurred to me, after reading this and Ms. Yvette's answer: are you (and everyone else who thinks these tags should go) missing the fact that `UIButton` is the **name of the class**? It's not "button in UIKit", the **widget's name is actually** "UIButton". That would explain a lot of this.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: No, I'm not missing that fact. It's just not especially relevant.

Comment: How is it not relevant? You don't think that a tag for a major class in a framework is a useful tag?

Comment: Is the fact that the class representing the concept "button" in [uikit] is named "uibutton" so important that the tag for the concept no longer works?

Comment: Yes, I think so: the entity `UIButton` is not simply "the concept 'button' in the context of UIKit", just like [std::string is probably more than "the concept 'string' in the context of the C++ standard library"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657050/are-end1-iterators-for-stdstring-allowed).

Comment: Well, if you insist, then at least be consequently explicit, and name it [uikit-uibutton], or it that [ios-uikit-uibutton] or even [ios-swift-uikit-uibutton]?

Comment: Sure, as long as you start using [phone] [apple] [operating-system] when you mean [ios].

Comment: @JoshCaswell: [apple] is a bad tag, though no worse than [microsoft]. Also does apple have some VoIP software phones? [phone] combined with company doesn't describe the hardware. [iphone] and [operating-system] would be a good choice for questions dealing with developing your own new os for an iphone...

Answer (score -2):

These tags are doing no harm: with the five available tag slots on a question, it's rare that a question can fill them up with high-level "expertise" tags. Once you've got [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch), and (if necessary) [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)/[objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objc), you're quickly getting into specifics at the level of classes. These specifics *do* aid categorization: not every question that touches on `UITableView` has that class as one of its *subjects* (e.g. [iOS MagicalRecord grouping and sorting for tableview. How do they work, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107081/ios-magicalrecord-grouping-and-sorting-for-tableview-how-do-they-work-exactly)) and subjects are what the tags indicate.

It also makes a difference for search. Compare ["uibutton toggle"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uibutton%20toggle) and ["[uibutton] toggle"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[uibutton]%20toggle). The question that seems likely to be most helpful ([How to use UIButton as Toggle Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882857/how-to-use-uibutton-as-toggle-button)) appears sixth in the first, and fourth in the second. This is not an exhaustive proof of anything: I don't know the exact nature of the effect on search, nor have I tested finding a question that is tagged as opposed to not tagged, but it does make some things easier to find and be sure of.

There's also nothing inherently wrong with the title and the tags both mentioning the subject of the question. In fact, that's completely natural. We eschew the *forcing* of tag-like content into titles, but the converse is equally stupid. Compare:

- Forced addition: "UIButton: why can't I make it blink?"
- Forced removal: "Why can't I make it blink?"
- Natural: "Why won't my UIButton blink?" (or, really best would be: "UIButton won't blink despite <summary of context>)

Google does seem to do better with keywords in titles (I'm not sure how much it uses tags), but on-site the tags have a non-troublesome, sometimes even helpful effect. They should be kept.

Comment: The comparison should have been more like "[uibutton] toggle" pre-change and "[uikit] [button] toggle" post-change.

Comment: What change, @Deduplicator?

Comment: Second paragraph, and the change proposed in the question.