# Do we need the [gkgamesession] tag, are our tags too microscopic?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need the [gkgamesession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gkgamesession) tag? It has 5 posts.

I'm just wondering if we can become too microscopic on our tags and would like to know what the community thinks.

I'm erring on wanting tags to be a bit broader than this, as we could end up with millions of tags and although we use them to help search, the words within the questions also help to search particular topics.

Comment: Low usage isn't a reason not to have a tag. If it describes something that's too specific -- for example, a `boost-asio-io_service-poll_one` is about a _single method_, so that ain't good, but `boost-asio` is about a library, so it's probably fine -- then it might be bad, but this doesn't seem to be that.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes yes I edited my post to reflect this and I don't think we need tags for topics that wouldn't get many posts, otherwise we could have millions of tags

Comment: It's a tag that, like this one, is about a library (well, in this case it's a _little_ more complicated, but for the most part, it's basically a tag for a library). Does the fact that so few people have questions about it mean that no one should be allowed to tag their questions well?

Comment: The tag is named for a class in the [tag:gamekit] library so we should probably retag to that.

Comment: @approxiblue can you write an answer please? would like some different viewpoints on it, if possible

Comment: Closely related: [Do we need tags like UIButton, UILabel, etc.?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314026/do-we-need-tags-like-uibutton-uilabel-etc)

Comment: I don't know enough about the library to add an answer. All the [tag:gkgamesession] questions could just be tagged [tag:game-center], although tags for a single class are not exactly unheard of, e.g. [tag:httpurlconnection].

Answer (score 7):

> Do we need the gkgamesession tag?

The tag seems to adequately categorize the questions it is applied to, and does not seem to be ambiguous.

> It has 5 posts?

Every tag has to start somewhere. The fact that a tag does not have many questions is not a sign that the tag should be removed, but rather that the tag needs more questions.

> Im just wondering if we can become too microscopic on our tags and would like to know what the community thinks. [sic]

This depends on how you define microscopic.

If the scope of a tag is truly so minor that it no longer adequately categorizes the questions it is applied to, it is not serving its purpose.

If the tag adequately categorizes the questions it is applied to, and it is not ambiguous, then we should keep it.

> I'm erring on wanting tags to be a bit broader than this, as we could end up with millions of tags and although we use them to help search, the words within the questions also help is to search particular topics.

What is the problem with having millions of tags?

A user can only apply a maximum of 5 tags to a question, and the hope is that they choose the 5 most relevant tags.

All in all, I say that tags should be evaluated on a case by case basis using [the previously established metrics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/310756)

#### Related

[When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate)